# ActionScript to Objective-C conversion tool

Tags: objective-c, ios, actionscript

We have an application written in **ActionScript 3** using Flash. Now it's time to port this app to iOS. So we need to convert a lot of code to **Objective-C** syntax. I think, this task must be automated, which excludes useless and time consuming hand work stuff.

In previous project I had similar development iteration - convert Java to ActionScript 3. And this was achieved with open source conversion tool [J2AS3](http://code.google.com/p/j2as3/).

Does exist such tool or some open source project for converting *ActionScript 3 to Objective-C*?
Or I should to start write it myself from scratch?

**UPDATE**. The only valuable info what I've found is a thread in stackoverflow: [Converting Actionscript syntax to Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870882/converting-actionscript-syntax-to-objective-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe makes a tool called Packager for iPhone that does this.  Check it out here: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/

From their site:

> The Packager for iPhone, which is a
>   feature of Adobe Flash® Professional
>   CS5 software and the Adobe AIR® SDK
>   2.0.1, offers Flash developers a fast and efficient method to reuse existing
>   code from ActionScript 3 projects to
>   deliver deliver iOS applications for
>   devices including the iPhone. The
>   Packager for iPhone download is also
>   available as a standalone technology...

Comment: Thank you. Of course, I've read 'bout it, but i was wandering, does this tool produce Objective-C code or binaries? Have you experience of using it?

Comment: @ajukraine I have not used it, but it is my understanding that it produces the binary directly.

Answer (score 0):

Flash CS5 can package as3 to be run on an iPhone.  Check it out [here](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/).